# Error defining BoundedVec as a Pallet Storage the trait `Decode` is not implemented for `sp_runtime::BoundedVec

Tags: rust, storage, boundedvec

I have a StorageValue defined as follows

```
    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn reg_students)]
    pub type RegStudents<T: Config> =
        StorageValue<_, BoundedVec<StudentId, T::MaxStudents>, ValueQuery>;
```

and the types are defined as follows

```
#[pallet::constant]
type MaxStudents: Get<u16>;

pub type StudentId = u32;
```

I am getting the following error compiling

```
62  | pub trait StorageValue<T: FullCodec> {
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `frame_support::StorageValue::get`
help: consider introducing a `where` clause, but there might be an alternative better way to express this requirement
    |
103 |     #[pallet::storage where sp_runtime::BoundedVec<u32, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxStudents>: Decode]

StorageValue<_, BoundedVec<StudentId, T::MaxStudents>, ValueQuery>;
    |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Decode` is not implemented for `sp_runtime::BoundedVec<u32, <T as pallet::Config>::MaxStudents>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the impl.

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/src/sp_core/bounded/bounded_vec.rs.html#45

It requires `Get<u32>`.

Try:

```rs
#[pallet::constant]
type MaxStudents: Get<u32>;
```